# Why does the Ubuntu SDK tell me, "do not use comma expression", and what should I use instead?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

So for example:

```
onCurrentlyExpandedChanged: flickable.DragOverBounds, flickable.contentHeight += itemHeight,console.log(itemHeight)
```

The commas will have a yellow underline, and the tooltip will tell me to not use comma expressions. What expression should I use instead? What expressions can I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
onCurrentlyExpandedChanged: { 
    flickable.DragOverBounds
    flickable.contentHeight += itemHeight
    console.log(itemHeight)
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do an && sort of expression, where item2 will only execute after item 1 has finished? Or will I have to do that via a function?

Comment: I don't think so. You have to create a function for this.